# How to merge named templates in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Suppose we have the following in, say, `_helpers.tpl`:

```
{{- define "app.selectorLabels" -}}
app.kubernetes.io/name: app
app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance
{{- end }}

{{- define "app.component.selectorLabels" -}}
{{ include "app.selectorLabels" . }}
app.kubernetes.io/component: component
{{- end }}

{{- define "app.labels" -}}
foo: bar
{{ include "app.selectorLabels" . }}
{{- end }}

{{- define "app.component.labels" -}}
{{ include "app.labels" . }}
{{ include "app.component.selectorLabels" . }}
{{- end }}
```

Now the `app.component.labels` named template - used , say, with `include` somewhere in svc.yaml or whatever - will contain the content of `app.selectorLabels` twice and will render as the following:

```
foo: bar
app.kubernetes.io/name: app
app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance
app.kubernetes.io/name: app
app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance
app.kubernetes.io/component: component
```

Is there any way to merge the two includes in `app.component.labels` definition so that the duplicates will merge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot merge templates since they output just text, it's not actual structured data for go. But you can do some tricks with dicts.

```
{{- define "app.component.labels" -}}
{{- $appLabels := fromYaml (include "app.labels" .) -}}
{{- $selectorLabels := fromYaml (include "app.component.selectorLabels" .) -}}
{{- $labels := merge $appLabels $selectorLabels -}}
{{ toYaml $labels }}
{{- end -}}
```

The key here is `fromYaml`, `toYaml` and the `merge` function. There are a few variations for `merge` and the order matters, you need to decide which way you want precisely. You can check the docs http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html

---

That said, it may be better to simply not include the selector labels in app labels in order to sidestep the problem altogether.

Comment: Is there any mechanism to define the `appLabels` variable in such a way so I can use it in other named templates too? Say, in an `app.component2.labels`?

Comment: @bagratte, not really. You can add it to the values dict that is read from the values file, but it becomes tricky with the order of execution. If something is trying to access it before you have added it, you have a problem.